# Trying to go through Lwt tutorial, but there seems to be a library problem

Tags: ocaml

I'm running Ocaml 3.12 on Ubuntu installed via Godi.

I'm going through the [Lwt tutorial](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/manual/).  I've started up the toplevel and done (as instructed):

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "lwt";;
```

The require of "lwt" seems to be successful (no complaints about not being able to find it).
Then a bit later I try:

```
# Lwt_io.read_char;;
```

And the toplevel complains:

```
# Error: Reference to undefined global `Lwt_io'
```

When I look in  ~/godi-3.12/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/lwt I see that lwt_io.cmi and lwt_io.mli files are present.  godi says I have version 2.2.1 of lwt installed.

I also tried running lwt-toplevel, but could not type anything into it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lwt_io module belongs to lwt.unix subpackage. Use it:

```
#require "lwt.unix";;
```